# Adding users not working in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I'm trying to create a new user account in my Linux machine.

I executed the following commands:

```
useradd -m test1
passwd test1
usermod -a -G sudo test1
chsh -s /bin/bash test1
```

The commands worked, but when I try to log in as the `test1` user, Kali does a loop motion and loops back into the username screen. I tried using an account that was not added into the system to test whether it's a bug and I got an error. Which means that the system knows that `test1` exists but it's not letting me in. Any thoughts or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: maybe kali linux is broken somehow. Its not a general purpose distro to be used as one's daily driver. Is this a livecd? is there any output when you run sudo grep test1 /etc/shadow ?

Comment: Can you `su test1`, or open a terminal session (i.e. press `CTRL+ALT+FX` where `FX` is one of the function keys `F1-F12`) and login as `test1` there?

Comment: This rather sounds like an error in your X session, try removing the file `/home/test1/.Xauthority` (as root) and maybe have a read of the `.xsession-errors` file.

Comment: I can su into test1 @txtechhelp

Comment: adduser insted of useradd?